# Como puedo sumar dos enteros largos pasados como un string? c#

Tags: c#, array, string

Primero de todo, quiero dar las gracias por tu tiempo a la hora de leer mi pregunta.
Soy nuevo con c# y en la programación en general, y estoy teniendo problemas con algo sencillo.
Quiero sumar dos enteros largos pasados como cadena de texto, he llegado al punto en el que descompongo las cadenas y las almaceno en dos arrays de una dimensión pero luego no soy capaz de  sumar ambas y recibir un resultado coherente.
Un saludo Isra.

### Edito 1

Añado el codigo por donde ya me he rendido....

```
' static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string num1, num2;
        int[] numeros1;
        int[] numeros2;
        int suma = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce un numero largo: ");
        num1 = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce un numero largo: ");
        num2 = Console.ReadLine();

        numeros1 = new int[num1.Length];

        for(int x = 0; x < num1.Length-1; x++)
        {
            numeros1[x] = num1[x];
        }

        numeros2 = new int[num2.Length];

        for (int x = 0; x < num1.Length - 1; x++)
        {
            numeros2[x] = num2[x];
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < numeros1.Length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < numeros2.Length; y++)
            {
                suma += (numeros1[x] + numeros2[y]);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("La suma de las dos cadenas introducidas es: {0}", suma);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }'
```

Comment: Saludos @IsraelMiguelSaura, como sos nuevo te invito a hacer un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), para enterder mas la forma en la que funcionemos, seria bueno que pongais un poco de codigo para poder ver cual es tu avance lo cual valoramos mucho.

Comment: Gracias por contestar.  He editado el post orignal y añadido el codigo...

Answer (score 3):

En C# existen algunas funciones que te ayudan a convertir. Debido a que quieres colocar cadenas largas te recomiendo que utilices la función Int64.Parse(string s). En C#, como en algunos otros lenguajes, no puedes sumar cadenas (con el +), el operador + funcionará para concatenar las cadenas que quieras "sumar". Por eso primero hay que convertirlas para luego sumarlas.

```
        ...
        string num1 = "", num2 = "";
        double suma = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce un numero largo: ");
        num1 = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce un numero largo: ");
        num2 = Console.ReadLine();

        suma = Int64.Parse(num1) + Int64.Parse(num2); //Aquí es la parte donde convierto las cadenas largas en enteros para poderlas sumar.
        Console.WriteLine("La suma de las dos cadenas introducidas es: {0}", suma);
        Console.ReadKey();
        ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, no conocia la funcion parse, supongo que al estar aun al principio del todo, el manual no ha llegado a esa parte.                                    Un saludo Isra

Comment: @Israelmiguelsaura No hay de qué amigo, estamos para ayudar. Saludos

Comment: Solo para ampliar un poco mas tambien esta la funcion Convert que este tiene varios metodos que puedes usar para convertir al tipo de dato que gustes. Es decir podrias hacer Convert.ToInt32(num1) o Convert.ToDecimal(num1).

Comment: @Israelmiguelsaura La función que te recomiendan es muy útil para números "grandes" en el mundo empresarial, pero no para números realmente grandes, como los que se usan en criptografía de clave pública o en ataque de problemas de análisis numérico. Ten presente esto cuando hayas ahondado en los temas de programación. Para manejar números muy largos se necesitan algoritmos especiales.

Comment: Exacto @LuisFernando, como mencionas, la función Convert tiene bastante utilidad. No recordaba esa función, gracias por retroalimentar.